# Update array element in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm having a data set which is by default have following:

```
summaries: [{client:'', type: '', mention: '', action: '', comment: '', button: true}],
```

I've a button which adds the same data set into summaries data:

```
addSummary() {
    this.summaryHeaders = true;
    this.summaries.push({
        client: '',
        type: '',
        mention: '',
        action: '',
        comment:'',
        button: true
    })
},
```

Now I'm having other button, while being clicked I want to update button attribute as false of that particular data set. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be using `v-for` loop to render the `summaries` array

So to the method which gets called on click which should update the button property pass, the single item from the array you are looping through

```
<duv v-for="(summary,index) in summaries">
    <p>{{summary}}</p>
    <button @click="updatProperty(summary, index)">Update button attribute</button>
</div>
```

then in your methods

```
methods:{
    updatProperty(summary){
        summary.button = false;
    }
}
```